# Django: make a list of the elements from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models

I'd like to test the view that does the creation of a Thing where you select multiple users (among other details).

I defined a Thing model, having a "**users**" ManyToManyField to the User model (from Django's shipped authentication app).

Here's my test code :

```
class ViewsTest(TestCase):
    def test_create(self):
        my_users = [...some User instances...]
        response = self.client.post("/create/", {...stuff...,
                                'users': [user.id for user in my_users]})
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
        created_thing = Thing.objects.get(...)
        self.assertListEqual(my_users, [user for user in created_thing.users.all()])
```

This test passes, so all is well, but I'm annoyed by the list comprehension at the end. Isn't there a more elegant way to get the **created_thing.users** as a list ?

I'm using Django 1.4.1.

Comment: Well I'm not sure and can't try it atm but you could try casting the queryset to a list

list(created_thing.users.all())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension is a typical way to create a list from a django `queryset` so what you did was perfectly fine.

What @PuercoPop suggested is fine too - using `list(created_thing.users.all())` because it forces the evaluation of the `queryset` into a list type object containing your user objects.

Comment: list() does work. I'm glad to know that list comprehensions are the typical way to go ; I wasn't quite comfortable with it. Now I'm going to relax ;) Thanks.